# Inner node data with HtmlAgilityPack C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack to read data/string from a webpage.

My html is here in fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7DWfa/1/

Here is my code

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(s);
if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null){
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode bodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
if (bodyNode != null)
{//what to do here to get title and href?
var inputs = from input in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                     where input.Attributes["class"].Value == "results-data-price-btn"
                     select input;

}
}
```

Please guid me how to get div values via classes

Comment: Title and Href of what?

Comment: If you just look into http://jsfiddle.net/7DWfa/2/  there are informations like price title and image src i want to get those

Comment: @Arran:i updated my question..i tried a lot of ways but no luck...

Comment: Using the xpath `//body/div[class=xyz]` will be easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: the below is untested, I've just quickly looked at the HTML of the page and tried to understand how it 'fits' together.

Each car 'result' has a `div` with the class `search-results-box`. So....

```
var rootNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode;
var allCarResults = rootNode.SelectNodes("//div[normalize-space(@class)='search-results-box']");
foreach (var carResult in allCarResults)
{

}
```

You have each 'car result' (as in, each item is now the entire section that represents one of the cars...so dig deeper....

Within each of these, the data of the car is within another `div`, with the class `search-results-data`...so....

```
var dataNode = carResult.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='search-results-data']");
```

Within *this*, you will now dig even deeper. The *title* of the car is within another element, specifically within a child `h2`...

```
var carNameNode = dataNode.SelectSingleNode(".//h2/a");
string carName = carNameNode.InnerText.Trim();
```

The *price* of the car is most difficult thanks to the horrible markup in the HTML.

It sits within a `font` element which is inside another `div`...

```
var carPriceNode = dataNode.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='results-data-price-btn']/font");
string carPrice = carPriceNode.InnerText.Trim(); // this will give you AED 24,500. Perform some logic to split that up so you just have the number...a
```

The problem is that the price is stuck together as "AED 24,500" in one element. Therefore you can easily get the element, but if you want just the number, that's logic you'll need to figure out for yourself to do.

The *image* itself, is fine. That's a level up in the markup, back up as a child under the `carResult`, so up we go.....:

```
var carImageNode = carResult.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='search-results-img']/descendant::img");
string carImageSource = carImageNode.GetAttributeValue("src", string.Empty);
```

**Re-edit**

All of the 'More Details about this used car' information is stuffed into one place, so the below will work for your example but *may* not work for all of them:

```
var descriptionNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='description']");

var entireDescription = descriptionNode.InnerText.Trim();

var splitUpDescriptionParts =
    entireDescription.Split(
        new[]
            {
                "More Details about this Used Car:", "Body Condition:", "Mechanical Condition:", "Doors:", "Cylinders:", "Body Style:",
                "Drive Type:", "Warrenty:", "Description:"
            },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Trim()).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));

string bodyCondition = splitUp.First();
string mechancialCondition = splitUp.ElementAt(1);
string amountOfDoors = splitUp.ElementAt(2);
string amountOfCylinders = splitUp.ElementAt(3);
string bodyStyle = splitUp.ElementAt(4);
string driveType = splitUp.ElementAt(5);
string warranty = splitUp.ElementAt(6);
string description = splitUp.Last();
```

Comment: This give me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on foreach loop

Comment: See my edit, the class name on the surrounding div actually has a space at the end, therefore it wouldn't find anything, so I have changed the XPath at the top to force it to strip the spaces from the class name first.

Comment: Do you mean getting the 'View Detail' link and opening that link in a browser or just getting the link?

Comment: I want to read information from "View Detail" link as i did in this page....here is html http://jsfiddle.net/wQrn9/

Comment: What *exact* details do you need from the page? Let me know that and I'll update my answer with that too.

Comment: :i need More Details about this Used Car: like Body condition,doors etc etc

Comment: I have added something else into my post.

Comment: ,thansk..buttell me one this..should i use same call inside foreach loop for More Details about this used car?

Comment: No, this can be outside it.

Comment: I need only url from main page and then will visit that url to get more details...if i can not do like this then it will be difficult for me to do one by one

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now - then yes, if you put it inside the `foreach` loop, it will take care of each one for you. Does that make sense?

Comment: :Can we do something with pagination?Eg,There are total of 100 records and shows 10 per page,how to get next page?can we do?

Comment: Maybe, but it will be difficult. You will have to figure out *how* the paging works to begin with. Does it just add something onto the URL? Something like `page=5` or `page=10`? Providing it's not done asynchronously using Javascript, you should be able to do it just using the HTMLAgilityPack. Find out how the paging works, then you can see if it's possible using HtmlAgilityPack on it's own.

Comment: yes paging style is too simple...for secnd page "url.com/search?page=2&sort=posted_desc"  and for page3 it is page=3...her is complete url ...http://uae.yallamotor.com/used-cars/search?page=2&sort=posted_desc